# Unable to access AJAX data [PHP]

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, .htaccess

A form on my homepage (`index.php`) opens a randomly generated URL in a new tab, after being submitted. That random url is running a script called `run.php`

```
<form action="/run.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" id="idgen" name="idgen" value="<?php echo $random ?>">
    <input type="text" name="userinput" id="userinput">
    <button type="submit" onclick="calcResult();">Go!</button>
</form>
```

There are JS functions on my homepage that use the `userinput` data to calculate a result.

I'm trying to use AJAX to send a value from my `index.php` to the random url generated by the form.

```
function calcResult() {
  var userinput = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
  var randomid = document.getElementById('idgen').value;

  // various functions

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://example.com/' + randomid, // same random url as the form sends to
            data: {result: "Hello!"}, // using simple result for testing purposes
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
           }
});
```

I added `<?php echo $_POST['result']; ?>` to the `run.php` file (the random url that the form opens is running `run.php`)

`console.log(response)` shows it working. It console logs the entire `example.com/<randomID>` source code (shows entire `run.php` code), and even replaces `<?php echo $_POST['result']; ?>` with "Hello".

However, this only works in the console. When that webpage is opened by the form, "Hello" is not shown.

I have a MySQL database that I insert values into from the *run.php* file. I tried to do the same for `$_POST['result'];` with no luck.

There are no console errors when I use the above code, nor are there any fatal errors in the error log.

**Extra info**

- The form submits to `run.php` which contains `header('Location: http://example.com/'.$_POST['idgen']);` in order to redirect to the random url.
- The random urls exist using a htaccess RewriteRule `RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ /run.php?idgen=$1 [L]`
- Attempted to use 'Flight' framework, but was runnning into issues when trying to use JS functions with it.

**Goal**

- The overall goal is to send the results (obtained from JavaScript functions on my homepage) to PHP. Such that they will display on the random url that opens after the form is submitted - so that I can display them, add them to the database etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can try windows.location of JavaScript and pass your value instead of header location.

Comment: I don't quite understand how I do that? `header('Location: http://example.com/'.$_POST['idgen']);` is in `run.php`, not on the homepage.

Comment: okay means what you get data from ajax that is display in console but not in page right?

Comment: That's right. The console shows the whole source code from `run.php` and i shows the data from ajax, but it doesn't show on the page, just the console.

Comment: okay no problem. take one div in page like <div id='result'></div>                                      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://example.com/' + randomid, // same random url as the form sends to
            data: {result: "Hello!"}, // using simple result for testing purposes
            success: function(response){
                $('#result').html(response);
           }
});

Comment: just take a div and give it one id like result and write code in success of ajax    $('#result').html(response); and check value is display in div or not

Answer (score 0):

In php u echo the URL to redirect to like

```
echo 'http://example.com/' . $_POST['idgen'];
die();
```

If you want php to do redirect you shouldn't use Ajax.

Non ajax method, you almost got it right

```
<form action="run.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" id="idgen" name="idgen" value="<?php echo $random ?>">
    <input type="text" name="userinput" id="userinput">
    <button type="submit">Go!</button>
</form>
```

The above code will submit to run.php directly, and you can use your original header() function to do redirect.

**in php**

```
header('Location: http://example.com/'.$_POST['idgen']);
```

Update

```
/* RUN.PHP PAGE - THE PAGE TO RECEIVE THE JAVASCRIPT RESULTS */

<?php

    $endurl = $_POST['idgen']; ?>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['userinput'])) {

  // DATABASE LOGIN DETAILS HERE
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            echo 'false';
            die();
            //die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

            //Just echo False so Javascript knows what's happening.
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO mydatabasename (userinput,randurl)
        VALUES ('$_POST[userinput]','$_POST[idgen]')";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            //echo "New record created successfully"; // You cannot echo anything else if you want to do a redirect. Try error_log?
            error_log('New Record Created Successfully');
        } else {
            echo 'false';
            die();
            //echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            //let javascript know you failed.

        }

        $conn->close();
           // header('Location: http://example.com/'.$endurl);
           echo 'http://www.example.com/'.$endurl;
           die();
    }
    else if (isset($_GET['idgen'])) {
      // DATABASE LOGIN DETAILS HERE
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {

            //die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            error_log('Connection Failed:' . $conn->connect_error );
            echo 'false';
            die;
        }

        $sql = "SELECT userinput FROM mydatabasename WHERE randurl = '".$_GET['idgen']."'";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result) {
                if ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

            }
            $result->close();
      }
      $conn->close();
    }
    ?>
```

Then in javascript you need to check for false

```
function calcResult() {
  var userinput = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
  var randomid = document.getElementById('idgen').value;
```

// various functions

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://example.com/' + randomid, // same random url as the form sends to
    data: {
    result: "Hello!",
    userinput: userinput,
    idgen: randomid

    }, // using simple result for testing purposes
    success: function(response){
        if (response != 'false') {
        window.location.replace(response);
        } else {
        alert('error encountered');
        }
   }
```

});

Comment: I just tried that but instead it tried to open `http://example.com/<html><head>%20%20%20%20<title>Title%20Goes%20%7C%20Here</title><link%20rel="icon"%20type="image/png".............` The entire source code

Comment: I put `echo 'http://example.com/' . $_POST['idgen']; die();` in the `run.php` file and remove `header('Location: http://example.com/'.$_POST['idgen']);`?

Comment: yes remove the header part. only echo the URL. so the javascript will redirect to the URL you specify

Comment: It's still doing the same thing, the url becomes `example.com/<html>[entire run.php source code here]</html>` and it says 'bad request'

Comment: Your $_POST['idgen'] wasn't populated properly.  Now it's populated. please check your console that your POST values are correct.

Comment: Please see the above updated ajax code where your field values are being sent together with ajax under DATA

Comment: if still facing problems with ajax please use above suggested non ajax method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137765/discussion-between-someone-special-and-pebble).