# Using hidden inputs to POST JavaScript function result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a single form input on my homepage `userinput`. The homepage also contains a JavaScript function that uses that `userinput` value to calculate a result.

```
<form action="/run.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" id="idg" value="<?php echo $rand ?>"> // gets random url, can be ignored
    <input type="text" name="userinput" id="userinput">
    <button type="submit" onclick="calcResult();">Go!</button>
</form>

<script>
    function calcResult() {
        var userinput = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
        var result = userinput + 10; // want to POST result in a hidden input field w/ form
</script>
```

I'm trying to find a way in which a user can enter their input, submit the form, the JavaScript takes that `userinput` and calculates a result, then that result is POST'ed along with the `userinput` in the form.

The problem I can forsee with this method is that:

- The JavaScript function needs the `userinput` before it can calculate the result. However, the only way to get the `userinput` is to submit the form, which means the form data will be POSTed before the JavaScript result is returned.

My attempted solution(s):

- I've been attempting to use AJAX ([Unable to access AJAX data [PHP]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42715773/unable-to-access-ajax-data-php)) and have been consistently running into issues with that.

I was wondering whether it's possible to use a button (`type="button"`), instead of a submit (`type="submit"`) for the form. Then just use that button to call the JS function, then (somehow) submit the form (with the JS function result) *after* the JS function has completed? (either with plain JS or jQuery).

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing bracket for your `calcResult()` function. More importantly, you don't need to use AJAX for this... unless you are trying to submit the form without reloading the page... Why not just do the calculations on the server (PHP) side?

Comment: @Mikey That missing bracket isn't the case in the proper code, this is just the shortened, useful part of it. The page is reloading, so I would rather not use AJAX, I just don't know how I can run the JavaScript function (using the `userinput` before the form POST's)

Comment: @Mikey Because they are JavaScript algorithms, that I can't rewrite (yet). Plus the result of the JavaScript function needs to be inserted into my database, so has to be changed to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple approaches to do this,

*i'm gonna use jquery here instead of pure javascript to simplify it*

[without submission] you may check the event [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
$('#userinput').change(function (e) {
    // make some calculation
    // then update the input value
});
```

[with form submission] you will disable the submission using the object `preventDefault` inside the [`submit`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) event

```
$('#userinput').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // make some calculation
    // then update the input value

    // your ajax goes here OR resubmission of your form
    // to resubmit the form
    $(this).submit();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. One question: How would I go about resubmitting the form after the calculation are completed (using the `[with form submission]` code you wrote)?

Comment: so ? do you still have the same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

What you will find useful in this scenario is `event.preventDefault();`

```
function calcResult(e) {
    // Prevent the default action of the form
    e.preventDefault();

    var userinput = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
    var result    = userinput + 10;

    // Do whatever else you need to do

    // Submit the form with javascript
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

Comment: If I add `onclick="calcResult(event)"` to my button, then that submits without any console errors, however if I add the hidden field `<input type="hidden" name="hiddeninput" id="hiddeninput">` and within the function write `document.getElementById('hiddeninput').value = "hello";` then add `<?php echo $_POST['hiddeninput']; ?>` to the `run.php` page, nothing shows up

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for.  A way of having the information computed over PHP, without a page request.  This uses a form and then serializes the data, then transmits it to PHP and **displays the result from run.php**.

*Note*:
I did change your id to a name in the HTML so the code would serialize properly. I can change this per request.

**index.php**

```
$rand = rand(10,100);

?>

<form action="javascript:void(0);" id="targetForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="idg" value="<?php echo $rand ?>">
    <input type="text" value="12" name="userinput" id="userinput">
    <button onclick="ready()">Go!</button>
</form>

<div id="result"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function ready() {
    $.post('run.php', $('#targetForm').serialize(), function (data) {
        $("#result").html(data);
    })
}
</script>
```

**run.php**

```
<?php

echo floatval($_POST['userinput']) * floatval($_POST['idg']);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is by `onSubmit`

```
  <form action="/run.php" method="POST" onSubmit="return calcResult()">
    <input type="hidden" id="idg" value="<?php echo $rand ?>"> // gets random url, can be ignored
    <input type="text" name="userinput" id="userinput">
    <button type="submit" onclick="calcResult();">Go!    </button>
 </form>
```

And when you return true then only form will submit.

```
<script>
  function calcResult() {
    var userinput = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
    var result = userinput + 10; // want to POST result in a hidden input field w/ form
   return true;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your question is there any indicator that your task requires AJAX. You're just trying to change an input value right when you submit. AJAX is not needed for that.

First, attach an `onsubmit` event handler to your form instead of using an `onclick` attribute on your button. Notice, we are not stopping the form from submitting with `return false` as we still want the form to submit.

For convenience, let's add an ID to your form and let's add a hidden input field to store the calculated value.

(Side-remark: you don't need to use `document.getElementById(ID)` if the `ID` is a string with no dashes i.e. `document.getElementById('userinput')` can be shortened to just `userinput` )

```
<form action="/run.php" method="POST" target="_blank" id="theform">
    <input type="hidden" id="idg" value="<?php echo $rand ?>">
    <input type="text" name="userinput" id="userinput">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddeninput" id="hiddeninput">
    <button type="submit">Go!</button>
</form>

<script>
// this will be called right when you submit
theform.onsubmit = function calcResult() {
    // it should update the value of your hidden field before moving to the next page
    hiddeninput.value = parseInt(userinput.value, 10) + 10;
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: This seems like an ideal solution because it's so simple, but when I add `<?php echo $_POST['hiddeninput']; ?>` to `run.php`, nothing shows up (there's no console errors or anything like that either)

Comment: I just tested it... You've also added `<input type="hidden" name="hiddeninput" id="hiddeninput">` to your form right? Which browser are you using by the way? Maybe try adding `return true;` in the function as shown in my last edit.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if there's a basic error I'm making https://jsfiddle.net/Pebbley/1s812twg/  or whether it's because calcResult is no longer being called?

Comment: It should be **echo $_POST['hiddeninput'];**.

Comment: That still doesn't work unfortunately. No console errors either.

Comment: This is as much as I can help you. This [code](http://pastebin.com/NtHCGPgv) works for me. If it doesn't, then probably go for another answer here.

Comment: Still no luck, I appreciate the help none the less.

Comment: One last suggestion. It might be that the function is not being fired because of your browser. I would first add an alert() statement in the function. Then see if the alert pops up after clicking on button. If it doesn't then it means the function is not being called. Then I suggest attaching onsubmit using [another approach](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp). If that still doesn't work, then I am truly out of ideas.

Comment: It's strange, I was just trying it again and your solution actually does work (it runs the function, POSTs to run.php and I can add it to the database). So now I'm wondering whether it's an issue with my PHP code as to why `<?php echo $_POST['hiddeninput' nor 'userinput' etc.]; ?>` is showing